# program seems to skip a section of an if statement, moving to the else statement before moving back to the correct place

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am learning Java and have written a simple login program to test that I can use the things I have learnt correctly, up until now I have usernames and passwords stored as individual variables. I decided to use a switch statement to store usernames and passwords and assign them based on the user ID the user enters. This is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int user_attempt = 0;
    int pass_attempt = 3;
    Boolean LoginSuccessful;
    String user_name = null;
    String pass = null;

    System.out.println("Enter your user ID: ");
    int user = input.nextInt();

    switch (user){
    case 1: user_name = "lucas";
            pass = "password";
        break;
    case 2: user_name = "dave";
            pass = "password2";
        break;
    default: System.out.println("User ID not valid");
    }


    while(user_attempt < 5){

    System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
    String username = input.nextLine();


    if (username.equals(user_name)){
        while(pass_attempt > 0){
        System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
        String password = input.nextLine();
        if(password.equals(pass)){
            System.out.println("Login Sucessful");
            LoginSuccessful = true;
            break;
        }
        else{
            pass_attempt--;
            System.out.println("Incorrect password, attempts remaining  " + pass_attempt);
        }
    }
        break;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Username is not valid!");
        user_attempt++;
    }

    }

    if(LoginSuccessful = true){
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Login Failed.");
    }
   }
```

}

Everything seems to work fine except when I run the program and enter a user ID I get this

Enter your user ID: 
1
Enter your username: 
Username is not valid!
Enter your username:

instead of

Enter your user ID: 
1
Enter your username:

I cant work out why this is happening as the program functions normally from this point on, letting me enter a username and password and performing the correct functions if they are correct/incorrect. Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Add an `input.nextLine();` before `while(user_attempt < 5){` to consume the newline / carriage return left by `nextInt()`

Comment: Thanks, that worked and the program now works the way I wanted it to

Comment: Actually I think this has only patched the problem rather than fixed it, if I make any edits to the code then when I run it the problem comes back.

Comment: @lucasRHCP - Well, if you want to fix it, use `Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine())` and then remove the *additional* `nextLine()`. This will fix it *properly*. Beware of `NumberFormatException` though :)